# Spring SFTP Integration : Can we copy multiple files from remote to local based on single trigger file

Tags: spring, triggers, spring-data, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am working wiht Spring SFTP integration. My use case is to copy multiple csv files from remote directory when _SUCCESS trigger file is written to that particular directory. So basically one process will write multiple CSV files to remote directory and once every thing is done it will create a trigger file _SUCCESS, now sftp inbound channel needs to consume all those .csv files.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your SFTP Inbound Channel Adapter fully based on the `_SUCCESS` pattern (or whatever is that file trigger looks) and proceed downstream with an `MGET` command via SFTP Outbound Gateway: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

Comment: Hi Artem , can you please elaborate more on this. At this moment i have a SftpInboundFileSynchronizer which is synchronising everything to local directory as  soon it polls